# Conditional slicing in a 2-dimensional array in R

Tags: r, arrays, filter, slice

I have a two-dimension array made up from latitude(dimension 1) and longitude(dimension 2) coordinates. The position of each pair of lat,long coordinates corresponds to a position in a 3-dimensional array of temperature data (Third dimension representing depth).

I would like to extract the positions of lat long coordinates such that the latitude is valued 60<lat<70 and -60<long<-50  so that I can relate them to the temperature array and extract temperature data for particular regions. I am new to R, and programming in general, so this has been quite the problem for me.

```
#Extracts latitude and longitude matrices into variables
nav_lat <- ncvar_get(nc,"nav_lat")
nav_long <- ncvar_get(nc,"nav_lon")

#Overlays lat and long matrices to create pairs
nav_latlong <- array(c(nav_lat,nav_long),dim=(c(1442,398,2)))

region <- filter(nav_latlong,between(60,70) & between(-60,-50))
```

Is this what you mean by a small reproducible example?:

```
library(tidyverse)

vector_1 <- c(5,9,3)
vector_2 <- c(10,11,12)
result <- array(c(vector_1,vector_2),dim=c(3,3,2))

region <- filter(result,between(result[,,1],5,10) & between(result[,,2],10,12))
```

SO here I would want to extract pairs where the first element is between 5 and 10, and the second element is between 10 and 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another option:

```r
#example
set.seed(1)
lat <- matrix(runif(9, 50, 80), nrow = 3)
long <- matrix(runif(9, -70, -50), nrow = 3)
latlong <- array(c(lat, long), dim = c(3,3,2))

latlong
#> , , 1
#> 
#>          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#> [1,] 57.96526 77.24623 78.34026
#> [2,] 61.16372 56.05046 69.82393
#> [3,] 67.18560 76.95169 68.87342
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] -68.76427 -56.25954 -60.04602
#> [2,] -65.88051 -62.31793 -55.64763
#> [3,] -66.46886 -54.60317 -50.16188


#create filter mask
mask <- array(dim = c(3,3,2))
mask[,,1] <- dplyr::between(latlong[,,1], 60, 70)
mask[,,2] <- dplyr::between(latlong[,,2], -60, -50)
mask <- mask[,,1] & mask[,,2]
mask
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#> [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

#apply mask to get lat long pairs
apply(latlong, 3, \(x) x[mask])
#>          [,1]      [,2]
#> [1,] 69.82393 -55.64763
#> [2,] 68.87342 -50.16188
```

Edit
extract temperatures

If you want to know the indexes for the lat long in the original array, you can use `which(mask, arr.ind = TRUE)`. You don't need `mask == TRUE` because `mask` is already logical (i.e., matrix of TRUE and FALSE). Alternatively, you can just apply the mask to your temperature matrix (assuming it is the same dimensions). see below.

```r
#temperature example
set.seed(32)
temperatures <- matrix(runif(9, -20, 20), nrow = 3)
temperatures
#>            [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,]  0.2336209   9.152789 10.141508
#> [2,]  3.7923355 -13.920497 14.082492
#> [3,] 12.3498853  18.247490  6.937671

#get the temperatures
temperatures[mask]
#> [1] 14.082492  6.937671
```

Or even better would be to add the temperatures to the lat long array and extract everything at once, so that you have a nice data output:

```r
all_data <- abind::abind(latlong, temperatures, along = 3)
all_data
#> , , 1
#> 
#>          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#> [1,] 57.96526 77.24623 78.34026
#> [2,] 61.16372 56.05046 69.82393
#> [3,] 67.18560 76.95169 68.87342
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] -68.76427 -56.25954 -60.04602
#> [2,] -65.88051 -62.31793 -55.64763
#> [3,] -66.46886 -54.60317 -50.16188
#> 
#> , , 3
#> 
#>            [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,]  0.2336209   9.152789 10.141508
#> [2,]  3.7923355 -13.920497 14.082492
#> [3,] 12.3498853  18.247490  6.937671

#get lat long and temperature
apply(all_data, 3, \(x) x[mask]) |>
  `colnames<-`(c("Lat", "Long", "Temperature"))
#>           Lat      Long Temperature
#> [1,] 69.82393 -55.64763   14.082492
#> [2,] 68.87342 -50.16188    6.937671
```

Comment: PS I wrote this before you added an example, so my answer does not match your example data.

Comment: Your answer looks great. I am probably a little older than some of you folk and so a little slower. I will take some time to look over this code - thank you :)

Comment: No worries, I completely understand. The key here is getting the indexing correct. Let me know if you need any clarifications.

Comment: Also, as someone who uses temperature data a lot, I would recommend looking into the `raster`, `stars`, and `sf` packages. They do a really good job at working with and processing spatial data in R.

Comment: your code worked excellently, thank you. Now, how would I return the positions of these pairs in the original matrix, instead of the coordinates themselves? I think I want to return all positions of the 'TRUE' elements in the mask. Would something like which(mask == TRUE, arr.ind = TRUE) work? Best, F.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but you don't need `==TRUE`. Alternatively, you could use the mask directly for your temperatures. See the edit above.